# How to enter ^A in screen command

Tags: linux, shell

I wish to enter `Ctrl-A` to the terminal which will move the cursor to the very beginning of my current command line.

However, if I were using `screen` within the terminal, I was not aware of any way of entering `Ctrl-A` directly to the terminal instead of the default behavior.

Does anyone know how I could enter `Ctrl-A` directly to the terminal?

Comment: "Ctrl-A, A" - it is the `screen` command to send <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> to inside of the screen, documented at https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Default-Key-Bindings as `C-a a
(meta)
Send the command character (C-a) to window.` (C-a means Ctrl-A)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gnu `screen` documents how to use its command key <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd>, check the exception  in "5.1 Default Key Bindings" section of the documentation:

https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Default-Key-Bindings

> 5.1 Default Key Bindings
>
> As mentioned previously, each keyboard command consists of a `C-a` followed by one other character. For your convenience, all commands that are bound to lower-case letters are also bound to their control character counterparts (with the exception of `C-a a`; see below).
>
> `C-a a`
>   (meta)
>   Send the command character (C-a) to window.

So, press <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> then <kbd>A</kbd> to send <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> signal into program running inside the gnu `screen`.